# IE doesnt accept font as initial using important

Tags: internet-explorer, css

In chrome, it is ok to use `font: initial !important;`. But in IE(9), it's not getting inital value.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The CSS3 [`initial`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#initial) keyword isn't [supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#keywords) in any version of IE.

Comment: Re IE, the information is confirmed by Microsoft’s own page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh781508.aspx#keywords

Comment: WOOOOW "IE IS GETTING BETTER" THEY SAID. IE10 REALLY WOW.

Comment: Still the same in IE11

Answer (score 15):

@Adrift is entirely correct that IE does not currently (IE11) support `initial`. But to answer the question "How can I solve this?"...

```
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-stretch: normal;
font-size: medium;
line-height: normal;
font-family: serif; /* depends on user agent */
```

Answer (score 6):

I just came accross this bug for line-height and min-height.

On IE, replace "initial" by "auto" or "inherit".
Eg :

```
/*IE*/
line-height: inherit !important;
/* Rest of the world */
line-height: initial !important;

/*IE*/
min-height: auto !important; 
/* Rest of the world */
min-height: initial !important;
```

Comment: Fabulous! It works like a charm. I just wonder what are the differences among them.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft unfortunately doesn't accept `font-size: initial`.

The actual "initial" value specified in the docs is `font-size: medium`.

Microsoft doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530759(v=vs.85).aspx

Mozilla doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size